# ¿Cómo guardar en input quien inicio sesión?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo mi inicio de sesión, cuando me logueo necesito que el nombre con el que inicie sesión se muestre en un input en el formulario referido como `prueba1.html`, ¿ Alguna sugerencia?

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    read(0);

   $("#Validar").click(function() {
     validar();
   });

});

function read(Id) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/API/usuario/",
        data: {
            param: 2,
            Id: Id
        }
    })

}

function validar() {

    if ($.trim($("#usuario").val()).length > 0 && $.trim($("#contrasena").val()).length > 0) {
        console.log("ok");

        var usuario = $.trim($("#usuario").val());
        var contrasena = $.trim($("#contrasena").val());
        var txtUser = $("#user");
        var altUser = $("#alertUser");
        var btnAU = $("#btnAU");
        var msgAHU = $("#msgAHU");
        var msgABU = $("#msgABU");
        var entrarMetodo1 = "entra";

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/API/usuario/",
            data:{
                entrarMetodo1: entrarMetodo1,
                param: 5,
                usuario: usuario,
                contrasena: contrasena
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
             if (data.length > 0) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('usrid',data[0]['Id']);
                window.location.href = "prueba1.html";
             }else {

                window.location.href="prueba.html";
             }

        });

    } else {
        console.log("Error al autenticar");
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        sessionStorage.removeItem('usrid');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
                <input type="text" id="usuario">
                <input type="password" id="contrasena">
                <button class="btn btn-info" id="Validar">Iniciar</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prueba.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**API**

```
public function validate($usuario, $contrasena)
    {
        $this->conn->OpenConnection();
        $conSQL       = $this->conn->getConnection();
        $arrayUsuario = array();

        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario='$usuario' and contrasena='$contrasena'";

        if ($conSQL) {
            foreach ($conSQL->query($sqlQuery) as $row) {
                $arrayUsuario[] = array('Id' => $row['id'],
                    'usuario'                   => $row['usuario'],
                    'tipo'                      => $row['tipo'],
                    'nombre'                    => $row['nombre'],
                    'app'                       => $row['app'],
                    'apm'                       => $row['apm'],
                    'contrasena'                => $row['contrasena']);
            }
        }
        return $arrayUsuario;
        $this->conn->CloseConnection();
    }

}
```

Comment: Agregue el código en donde se hace el arreglo

Comment: Eiren ,  bien en mi respuesta cambiaría el `name` por `nombre` ya que es lo que retorna su `API` :)

Answer (score 2):

Si está utilizando [sessionStorage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) para almacenar los valores en un Objeto asociado a la sesión actual, simplemente debería seguir el camino con el cuál almacena el `id` , `sessionStorage.setItem('usrid',data[0]['Id']);` del usuario, para almacenar también el nombre.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('nombre', data[0]['name']);// name o nombre :)
```

**Es indispensable que la llamada `Ajax` tenga una clave nombre que retorne en efecto el nombre del usuario `logueado`** *(esto no es comprobable aún ya que no añadió el código del backend para saber que está devolviendo)* , una vez almacenado el nombre al hacer la re dirección a *(prueba1.html)* solo recuperaría el valor y asignaría al input.

```
document.getElementById('nombre').value = sessionStorage.getItem('name'); //name o nombre
```